# Using DD to produce an Image results in empty image

Tags: disk-image, dd, android

I am trying to take an image of my Android phone.  Specifically I have tried to image the system and boot partitions.  The imaging process appears to work correctly when using dd.  However, when I attempt to mount the image in a loopback device the image appears to be empty.  I also tried to see file contents by piping through cpio.  Basically, I am trying to validate the image that I took.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a problem with how I took the image or validation or both?  Here are the steps to took (you'll see on the system partition below but I used the same process for boot)

```
[root@localhost platform-tools]# ./adb devices
List of devices attached
99000421100783  device
```

```
[root@localhost platform-tools]#./adb shell
shell@C6730:/ $ su
```

```
root@C6730:/ # cat /proc/partitions

major minor  #blocks  name

 179        0    7634944 mmcblk0
 179        1      65536 mmcblk0p1
 179        2       1024 mmcblk0p2
 179        3       1024 mmcblk0p3
 179        4       1024 mmcblk0p4
 179        5       1024 mmcblk0p5
 179        6       1024 mmcblk0p6
 179        7       1024 mmcblk0p7
 179        8       1024 mmcblk0p8
 179        9       1024 mmcblk0p9
 179       10      16384 mmcblk0p10
 179       11       1024 mmcblk0p11
 179       12       1024 mmcblk0p12
 179       13       1024 mmcblk0p13
 179       14       1536 mmcblk0p14
 179       15       1536 mmcblk0p15
 179       16       2048 mmcblk0p16
 179       17       8192 mmcblk0p17
 179       18       4096 mmcblk0p18
 179       19       8192 mmcblk0p19
 179       20       8192 mmcblk0p20
 179       21     819200 mmcblk0p21
 179       22     658432 mmcblk0p22
 179       23      16384 mmcblk0p23
 179       24       6144 mmcblk0p24
 179       25       8192 mmcblk0p25
 179       26       1024 mmcblk0p26
 179       27       1024 mmcblk0p27
 179       28       5120 mmcblk0p28
 179       29    4718592 mmcblk0p29
 179       30    1048576 mmcblk0p30
 179       31       8192 mmcblk0p31
 259        0      20480 mmcblk0p32
 259        1       4096 mmcblk0p33
 259        2      16384 mmcblk0p34
 259        3      16384 mmcblk0p35
 259        4       1024 mmcblk0p36
 259        5       1024 mmcblk0p37
 259        6       1024 mmcblk0p38
 259        7       1024 mmcblk0p39
 259        8      20480 mmcblk0p40
 259        9      20480 mmcblk0p41
 259       10       4096 mmcblk0p42
 259       11       4096 mmcblk0p43
 259       12      95215 mmcblk0p44
 179       32        512 mmcblk0rpmb
 179       64   30183936 mmcblk1
 179       65   30182912 mmcblk1p1
 254        0    4718592 dm-0
 254        1    1048576 dm-1
```

```
root@C6730:/ # parted /dev/block/mmcblk0

GNU Parted 1.8.8.1.179-aef3
Using /dev/block/mmcblk0
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.

(parted) print
print
Model: MMC 8WMB3R (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/block/mmcblk0: 7818MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name             Flags
 1      4194kB  71.3MB  67.1MB  fat16        modem
 2      71.3MB  72.4MB  1049kB               sbl1
 3      72.4MB  73.4MB  1049kB               sbl1bak
 4      73.4MB  74.4MB  1049kB               sdi
 5      75.5MB  76.5MB  1049kB               DDR
 6      79.7MB  80.7MB  1049kB               aboot
 7      80.7MB  81.8MB  1049kB               abootbak
 8      81.8MB  82.8MB  1049kB               rpm
 9      82.8MB  83.9MB  1049kB               rpmbak
10      83.9MB  101MB   16.8MB               boot
11      101MB   102MB   1049kB               tz
12      102MB   103MB   1049kB               tzbak
13      103MB   104MB   1049kB               pad
14      104MB   105MB   1573kB               modemst1
15      105MB   107MB   1573kB               modemst2
16      107MB   109MB   2097kB               reserve1
17      109MB   117MB   8389kB               dnand
18      117MB   122MB   4194kB               bfss1
19      122MB   130MB   8389kB               bfss2
20      130MB   138MB   8389kB  ext4         persist
21      138MB   977MB   839MB   ext4         system
22      977MB   1652MB  674MB   ext4         cache
23      1652MB  1668MB  16.8MB               recovery
24      1668MB  1675MB  6291kB               misc
25      1678MB  1686MB  8389kB               fsg
26      1686MB  1687MB  1049kB               fsc
27      1687MB  1688MB  1049kB               ssd
28      1688MB  1693MB  5243kB               reserve2
29      1693MB  6525MB  4832MB               userdata
30      6525MB  7599MB  1074MB               internalstorage
31      7599MB  7607MB  8389kB  ext4         sysprop
32      7607MB  7628MB  21.0MB  ext4         carrier
33      7628MB  7633MB  4194kB               fotamng
34      7633MB  7649MB  16.8MB               fota
35      7649MB  7666MB  16.8MB               fotabk
36      7666MB  7667MB  1049kB               sdibk
37      7667MB  7668MB  1049kB               abootbk
38      7668MB  7669MB  1049kB               rpmbk
39      7669MB  7670MB  1049kB               tzbk
40      7670MB  7691MB  21.0MB               log
41      7691MB  7712MB  21.0MB               logwork
42      7712MB  7716MB  4194kB               bootwork
43      7716MB  7721MB  4194kB               rom
44      7721MB  7818MB  97.5MB               reserve3

(parted) q
q
```

```
root@C6730:/ # cd /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name
```

```
root@C6730:/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name # ls -l

lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 DDR -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p5
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 aboot -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p6
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 abootbak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p7
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 abootbk -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p37
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 bfss1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p18
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 bfss2 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p19
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 boot -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p10
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 bootwork -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p42
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 cache -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p22
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 carrier -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p32
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 dnand -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p17
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 fota -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p34
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 fotabk -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p35
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 fotamng -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p33
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 fsc -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p26
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 fsg -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p25
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 internalstorage -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p30
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 log -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p40
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 logwork -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p41
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 misc -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p24
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 modem -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 modemst1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p14
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 modemst2 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p15
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 pad -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p13
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 persist -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p20
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 recovery -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p23
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 reserve1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p16
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 reserve2 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p28
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 reserve3 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p44
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 rom -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p43
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 rpm -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p8
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 rpmbak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p9
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 rpmbk -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p38
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 sbl1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p2
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 sbl1bak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p3
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 sdi -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p4
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 sdibk -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p36
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 ssd -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p27
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 sysprop -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p31
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 system -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p21
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 tz -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p11
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 tzbak -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p12
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 tzbk -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p39
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1969-12-31 19:17 userdata -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p29
```

```
root@C6730:/ # dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p21 of=/mnt/media_rw/sdcard0/firmware-img/kyocerasystem.img bs=4096 conv=noerror,sync

204800+0 records in
204800+0 records out
838860800 bytes transferred in 40.461 secs (20732577 bytes/sec)
```

```
root@C6730:/ # exit

shell@C6730:/ $ exit

[root@localhost jeremy]:/ # losetup /dev/loop0 /home/jeremy/kyocerasystem.img
[root@localhost jeremy]:/ # mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0

mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Discarding device blocks:   4096/204800: done                            
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
51296 inodes, 204800 blocks
10240 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=209715200
7 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
7328 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840

Allocating group tables: 0/7: done                            
Writing inode tables: 0/7: done                            
Creating journal (4096 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: 0/7: done
```

```
[root@localhost jeremy]:/ # mount -t ext4 /dev/loop0 /mnt
[root@localhost jeremy]:/ # cd /mnt
[root@localhost jeremy]:/ # ls

lost+found


root@localhost jeremy]# dd if=kyocerasystem.img | cpio -ictv > kyocerasystem.txt
1638400+0 records in
1638400+0 records out
838860800 bytes (839 MB) copied, 25.1643 s, 33.3 MB/s
cpio: premature end of file


[root@localhost jeremy]:/ # less kyocerasystem.txt
(no contents to display - empty)
```

Comment: Please use the code/pre formatting options in the editor in order for the people trying to help you in the future not to get eye cancer.

Comment: Why in the world are you formatting the image file after mapping it to /dev/loop0? Of course you end up with an empty ext4 filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I see correctly then you are formatting the image you took earlier using `mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0`. Why are you doing that? Don't do that and the data will be there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not sure I understand your response.  Can you clarify?  The data I'm taking an image from is an ext4 partition.  Wouldn't you need to mount it as ext4?  BTW,  I tried without the  mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0 line and it made no difference.  I still end up with what appears to be an empty image.

Comment: You should mount it yes, but not FORMAT it afterwards!! Are you mounting the correct file? (Youre sending the output of dd to /mnt, yet you mount the image from /home)

Comment: I don't know what you are doing... Looking at the last two commands one can see that you're outputting the txt file to the current directory but you're using `less` on a file in /. And why the cpio? Either it's an ext4 or an archive (and probably not text like your txt extension suggests)...

Comment: >>>Are you mounting the correct file? (Youre sending the output of dd to /mnt, yet you mount the image from /home)
Yes, I am mounting from home and have the correct file.

Comment: >>>I don't know what you are doing... Looking at the last two commands one can see that you're outputting the txt file to the current directory but you're using less on a file..
Trying a second method to validate the image I took.  With DD being raw fromat you should be able to pipe it through CPIO to produce a text file that would contain the file structure of the image you have.  A text listing of the files in your img.

Comment: The image is empty because you are formatting it with the `mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0` command. If someone gave you a USB disk and you wanted to access its data, your first operation after connecting it to your computer should definitely ***not*** be to format it.

Comment: Yes, It is sinking in now.  I had the mistaken idea that because the image is raw you had to create a readable image with mkfs.  But really mkfs is formatting (wiping) the image.  (Plants palm on forehead!!!)  Thanks!

Comment: The `mkfs` command is shown in the [example section of the losetup man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/losetup8.html) although in this case you should definitely not do that ;)

Comment: I'll try taking the image again and not using mkfs.  Simple solution to my issue! It had me confused initially because I was new to using loopback.  I have taken raw images before and restored from raw images.  I just never tried to validate my image using a loopback to see if I could read it.  Thanks everyone for clarifying.  I'm sure I'm on the right track now.